# Passar valor de jTextField para NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho alguns `jTextfFields` onde preciso enviar para o `DAO` os seus valores, estes valores estão chegando corretamente no `DAO`, porém o retorno da `NameQuery` está sendo `null`. Não está havendo erro, somente o retorno é `null`, consequentemente não grava no banco.

O que é estranho ( para mim) ,é que depois de muito tentar, resolvi testar e descobri que  se eu setar os valores de forma que eles já iniciem preenchidos no `jTextField`, o retorno do `DAO` não é `null`, e sim o devido retorno.

No caso abaixo o "numero" é a `String` que veio do `jTextField` e foi enviada ao `DAO`, e `null` é o retorno da `NamedQuery`.(fiz um `sout`)

```
numero recebido:  5555
dao: null
```

Neste caso, setei manualmente para já iniciar o `jTextField` preenchido. O retorno é correto e grava no banco.

```
numero recebido:  5555
dao: 5555
```

Abaixo o que achei importante acrescentar para que alguém possa ajudar na questão do porque este comportamento e ajudar a corrigir os erros que podem estar causando isso, ou até outros erros. Obrigado

`Entidade` Carro

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Carro.findAll", query = "SELECT distinct c FROM Carro c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Carro.findByCarroId", query = "SELECT c FROM Carro c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Carro.findByCarroIdAndDescricao", query = "SELECT c FROM Carro c WHERE c.id = :id and c.numero = :numero"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Carro.findByCarroNumero", query = "SELECT c FROM Carro c WHERE c.numero = :numero")})
public class Carro implements EntidadeBase, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCarro")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "numeroCarro")
    private String numero;
```

Método no `DAO` para buscar o valor do `jTextField`

```
 public Carro buscarPorNumero(String numero) {
        System.out.println("NUMERO RECEBIDO: " + numero);
        EntityManager em = getEm();
        Carro carro = null;
        try {
            carro = (Carro) em.createNamedQuery("Carro.findByCarroNumero")
                    .setParameter("numero", numero)
                    .getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException | NonUniqueResultException nre) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nre.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("DAO: " + carro);

        return carro;

    }
```

Método para salvar, na `view`, deixei somente o código referente a questão específica para não poluir muito.

```
public void salvar() {
        CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();
        Locall locall = new Locall();
        Envio envio = new Envio();

        List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList();
        List<String> lista = new ArrayList();

        if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals("") == false) {
            lista.add(jTextField1.getText());
            System.out.println("PRIMEIRO:" + jTextField1.getText());
        }
        if (jTextField2.getText().trim().equals("") == false) {
            lista.add(jTextField2.getText());
            System.out.println("SEGUNDO:" + jTextField2.getText());
        }
        if (jTextField3.getText().trim().equals("") == false) {
            lista.add(jTextField3.getText());
            System.out.println("TERCEIRO:" + jTextField3.getText());
        }
        if (jTextField4.getText().trim().equals("") == false) {
            lista.add(jTextField4.getText());
            System.out.println("QUARTO:" + jTextField4.getText());
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            carros.add((Carro) carroDao.buscarPorNumero(lista.get(i)));
            System.out.println("Carro adicionado: " + lista.get(i));

        }
        envio.setCarros(carros);   

        try {
            EnvioDao ci = new EnvioDao();
            ci.save(envio);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gravado !");
            modelo.limpaLista();
            preencherTabela();
        } catch (Exception erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na Gravação:" + erro);
        }
        refresh();
        clearSelection();

    }
```

update1

```
if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals("") == false) {
        lista.add(jTextField1.getText().trim());
        System.out.println("PRIMEIRO:" + jTextField1.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Pelo seu código, você faz uma checagem do texto do `jTextField` para ver se o mesmo não está vazio e depois adiciona ele em uma lista para buscar os carros referentes aos textos (números). Verifique o seguinte: 1 - no `if` você trata o texto do `jTextField` com a função `.trim()` para retirar espaços da String, mas ao adicionar na lista você não usa a função (usa apenas o `.getText()`), isso pode estar causando o comportamento. 2 - No seu `if` do método `salvar()`, `.equals()` já retorna um `boolean` então não é necessário comparar com `false`, basta colocar um `!` na frente da sentença.

Comment: @Andre Gusmao obrigado, fiz o que sugeriu, e não resolveu, fiz mais um teste (adicionei a alteração em update 1) na questão acima, e funcionou, basicamente enviei  'id's' direto pro 'dao'  onde tem um método que busca por 'id', e gravou corretamente. Talvez o problema esteja na 'NamedQuery', ou não? Mas mesmo assim, para pegar o 'id', eu preciso buscar pelo ' numero' o número neste caso seria a 'descricao'.

Comment: Acho que a NamedQuery está correta. O problema é que ao executar o método `buscarPorNumero` do DAO o método pode estar caindo em uma das exceções que você declarou: **NoResult** caso não tenha carro com aquele número ou **NonUniqueResult** no caso de ter mais de um carro com o número que você está passando. Tem como você debuggar esse método para fornecer mais detalhes do que está acontecendo?

Comment: @Andre Gusmao obrigado novamente, devo ter deixado passar algo sobre seu primeiro comentário, pois ( conforme update 1, que editei agora) somente acrescentando o `trim()` ao passar  a `String`  para o `DAO` resolveu. O `jTextfield` está ficando com  um espaço vazio antes da `String` digitada, por isso o `null` de retorno do `DAO`.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Vou postar uma resposta para não deixar a pergunta pendente ok?

Comment: Sem problemas, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo seu código, no if:

```
if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals("") == false)
```

Você trata o texto do jTextField com a função .trim() para retirar espaços da String, mas ao adicionar na lista você não usa a função (usa apenas o .getText()), isso pode estar causando o comportamento uma vez que o valor passado para o DAO pode conter espaços.

Para resolver faça:

```
//O .equals já retorna um booleano
if (!jTextField1.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    //adicione o texto do jTextField tratado com o .trim()
    lista.add(jTextField1.getText().trim());
}
```